# How can I recover a number from the sum of that number and a random sample from a range?

Tags: python, math, cryptography, statistics, probability

Say I have some number `n==4`. Say I have some `m` drawn at uniform and random from the range `[0, 10]`. Let `p` be a long (say, 1024 entries) list of sums defined as `(n+m)`:

```
from __future__ import division
import random


myRand = random.SystemRandom()
n = 4
p = []
guess = []
guess_sum = 0 

for i in range(1024):
    m = myRand.randint(0, 10)
    p.append(n + m)
    guess.append(p[i] - 5)
    guess_sum += guess[i]
```

If the guesser knows the range from which `m` is drawn, then they can just subtract the average of this range, because the average is the center of a uniform random distribution. In our example, this corresponds to the line:

```
guess.append(p[i] - 5)
```

We can verify that this method produces a good estimate of the hidden number `n` by taking the average of the numbers in `guess[]`:

```
print("average of entries in guess[] is: ")
print(guess_sum/1024)
```

For example, I get results like: `3.9365234375, 3.9619140625, 4.177734375, 3.763671875, 4.0439453125`. By expectation, as the number of samples increases beyond `1024` we would expect the range of our results to tighten around `4`.

My question - how can a guesser recover the hidden number `n` if she does not know the range from which `m` is drawn? Assume that `m` is drawn from the same range for each experiment, and that `n` never changes.

I know someone must have answered this question, but I'm pretty stumped on how to move forward. Thank you!

Comment: You should consider asking this on math.se or even better stats.se

Comment: BTW, the answer is that you can't, in general: if you take the uniform distribution on [0, 10] and translate it by 4, you get the uniform distribution on [4, 14], which is indistinguishable from taking the uniform distribution on [3, 13] and translating it by 1, say. So unless you have some way of preferring U([0, 10]) over U([3, 13]) (for example), there is no unique answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method occurred to me after I posted this question, but it only works if we know the value of either `m_min` or `m_max` in advance. For this solution let us require `m_min = 0.`

Assume all variable names as defined in my original question.

The guesser only knows a string of values in the list `p`. As the guesser appends more numbers to the list `p` they can record two items: the `recorded_min` and the `recorded_max`, which correspond to the smallest number seen and the largest number seen, respectively.

Let us name the endpoints of the range from which `m` is drawn as `[m_min, m_max]`. Recall that the guesser wants to recover the value of the hidden number `n` from the entries in the list `p`.

`recorded_min` ~= `n` + `m_min`
`recorded_max` ~= `n` + `m_max`

Where `~=` means approximately equal.

After a long enough series of entries in the list `p`, we have some guess with some amount of confidence for the value of `recorded_min`, and likewise for `recorded_max`.

Note that `recorded_max - recorded_min` gives you `m_max - m_min`, which gives you the length of the range from which `m` is drawn.

Since we know that `m` is drawn at uniform random from this range, its center is `center = m_min + (recorded_max - recorded_min)/2`, or equivalently `center = m_max - (recorded_max - recorded_min/2)`. Since we required `m_min = 0`, we have the center of the random distribution.

We can now take the samples in the list `p` and subtract `center` from each of them, and average as before to arrive at our guess for `n`.

```
# python 2.7.10

from __future__ import division
import random

myRand = random.SystemRandom()
n = 4
p = []
guess = []
guess_sum = 0
num_experiments = 1024 * 80

m_min = 0
m_max = 0

while (m_max <= m_min):
    m_max = myRand.randint(0, 10)

recorded_min = float('inf')
recorded_max = 0
center = 0

for i in range(num_experiments):
    m = myRand.randint(m_min, m_max)
    p.append(n + m)
    if p[i] < recorded_min:
        recorded_min = p[i]
    if p[i] > recorded_max:
        recorded_max = p[i]

center = (recorded_max - recorded_min)/2

for i in range(num_experiments):
    guess.append(p[i]-center)
    guess_sum += guess[i]

print("average of entries in guess[] is: ")
print(guess_sum/num_experiments)
print("true value of n is: ")
print(n)
print("true m_min, m_max are: ")
print(m_min, m_max)
print("guessed m_min, m_max are: ")
print(recorded_min - guess_sum/num_experiments, recorded_max - guess_sum/num_experiments)
print("true center is: ")
print((m_min + m_max) / 2)
print("guessed center is: ")
print(center)
```

returns:

```
average of entries in guess[] is: 
4.00238037109
true value of n is: 
4
true m_min, m_max are: 
(0, 2)
guessed m_min, m_max are: 
(-0.00238037109375, 1.99761962890625)
true center is: 
1.0
guessed center is: 
1.0
```